# Two fields with the same name

Tags: php, sql

How would I get one id and not the other in the case of the following?

```
SELECT
    posts.id,
    posts.topic,
    posts.content,
    posts.date,
    posts.author,
    users.id,
    users.name,
    users.posts
```

When I get an id, it returns the user id, but I want the post id. How would I specify which one I want? I tried ["posts.id"] which apparently doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `AS` to alias them:

```
SELECT posts.id AS post_id, users.id AS user_id...
```

Comment: Thanks man, that worked. One more question though, can you still use posts.id within the query, or would you have to use post_id since using AS?

Comment: Just FYI, depending on the SQL dialect, often the AS keyword can be omitted if you don't like to type.

Answer (score 1):

You should alias the columns within the query, so that you can refer to them using the aliased column names.

```
SELECT
    posts.id as POSTID,
    posts.topic,
    posts.content,
    posts.date,
    posts.author,
    users.id,
    users.name,
    users.posts
```

i.e.

```
$row['POSTID']  <==  this is posts.id
$row['id']  <==  this is users.id (left as is)
```